# Phone Contacts in Python-how to save

Tags: python-3.x

I have created a class Contact with fname,lname,phone and email.  I then have class Addressbook to get all contacts, add contacts, search contacts, delete contacts, and save contacts. I then have a class Application to interface.  I can do everything but save the contacts as a text file.  Here are the relevant sections of code:

`

```
def view_all_contacts(self):
        all_contacts=self.__addressbook.get_all_contacts()
        for contact in all_contacts:
            print(contact)
```

`

```
def save_all_contacts(self):
        phonebook_file=open('phonebook.txt','w')
        for contact in Contact():
            phonebook_file.write(str(contact))
            phonebook_file.write("\n")
        phonebook_file.close()
    print('Addressbook has been saved.')
```

I get the exception TypeError: 'Contact' object is not iterable

Answer (score 0):

From your description, members of class `Contact''' are individual contacts, so they would not be`iterable'''.  The contacts need to be places into an ```iterable''' structure, for example, a dictionary or a list.  Code for a dictionary implementation might look something like this:

```
contacts = {} # create dictionary
contact = Contact("Abner Doe", address="15 Main St", ...) # create
contacts[1] = contact # add contact to dictionary
contact = Contact("Jane Doe", address="15 Main St", ...) # create
contacts[2] = contact # add contact to dictionary
for n in contacts:
    do_something_with(contact[n]) # or contact[n].do_something()
```